# Algebra equation for rank-3 tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, symmetry, tensor-calculus, group-theory, representation-theory

Suppose I work in $4$ dimensions. I have an algebraic equation in the following form, which contains a rank-3 tensor $X ^{\alpha \lambda \mu }$
\begin{equation}
X ^{\alpha \lambda \mu }\eta ^{\beta \xi }-X ^{\mu \lambda \alpha
}\eta ^{\beta \xi }-X ^{\beta \lambda \mu }\eta ^{\alpha \xi }+X
^{\beta \lambda \alpha }\eta ^{\mu \xi } =0,
\end{equation}
where $\eta ^{\beta \xi }$ is the Minkowski metric tensor.

What rank-3 tensor $X ^{\alpha \lambda \mu }$ satisfies the  above equation?

Comment: Define $X ^{\alpha \lambda \mu }W_\lambda\equiv Y^{\alpha \mu }$,   and multiply your vanishing tensor by $V_\xi$, so you now have just $Y ^{\alpha \mu }V ^{\beta }-Y ^{\mu \alpha}V^{\beta}-Y ^{\beta\mu }V^{\alpha}+ Y^{\beta \alpha } V^{\mu} =0$ to solve.

Comment: @CosmasZachos. Thanks. After calculating $Y ^{\alpha \lambda }$, how can we obtain $X ^{\alpha \lambda \mu }$ from $X ^{\alpha \lambda \mu }W_{ \lambda} 
 \equiv Y^{\alpha  \mu}$?

Comment: W is arbitrary, so you pick basis components.

Comment: @CosmasZachos. Thank you very much. Do you have any ideas for finding $X^{\alpha \lambda \mu }$ from equation $X^{\alpha (\lambda |\mu |}\eta ^{\beta \xi )}-X ^{\mu (\lambda |\alpha
|}\eta ^{\beta \xi )}-X ^{(\beta \lambda |\mu }\eta ^{\alpha |\xi )}+X
^{(\beta \lambda |\alpha }\eta ^{\mu |\xi )} =0$?